# Is "well" correct when using sarcasm?

Tags: word-request, usage, idiomatic-language

Is "well" correct when using sarcasm?

> "What's the time?" she asked.
>
> "**Well,** aren't you in a real hurry?" he said sarcastically.

I am not sure if the word "Well" belongs here, especially in a sarcastic comment. I am thinking there might be a more appropriate word, but I can't remember what it was. Also, can we really use "Well" in a sarcastic comment? Why? Doesn't sound like something you would say in a sarcastic remark.

Comment: It sounds like annoyance mixed with sarcasm (The *Well* indicating the annoyance - '*Well I never!*')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule against using the word "well" as part of a sarcastic comment, and comments of the form "Well, aren't you X", often with a sarcastic intent, are not uncommon. I see nothing wrong with the example sentence.